# Scrolling is locking on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4, smooth-scrolling

I got an issue with my website when I am trying to **scroll** website on mobile devices sometimes its locking and even when you slide finger on device website is not moving properly. On desktop scrolling working fine. I tried to find the solution but cant figure out what is wrong.

You can test it with developers tools on 375 px resolution or in mobile devices [here](http://weddingrent.pl)

Bootstrap 4 template: `NOW UI Kit by Creative Tim`

I thought problem is with cookie script but when I disable it by commenting  in HTML problem is not solving. I tried to comment parts of my JS file but still not working.

There is my JS Script:

```
    var selectedClass = "";
    $(".filter").click(function () {
        selectedClass = $(this).attr("data-rel");
        $("#gallery").fadeTo(100, 0.1);
        $("#gallery div").not("." + selectedClass).fadeOut().removeClass('animation');
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("." + selectedClass).fadeIn().addClass('animation');
            $("#gallery").fadeTo(300, 1);
        }, 300);
    });
    $( "#scrollDown" ).click(function() {
        $( "html, body" ).animate({
          scrollTop: 600
        }, 600, function() {
          // Animation complete.
        });
      });

      //Gallery Animations
      baguetteBox.run('.grid-gallery', { animation: 'slideIn' }); 

      //Anchor Function

      function scrollToAnchor(aid){
        let aTag = $("a[name='"+ aid +"']");

        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: aTag.offset().top}, 900);
    }

      //Menu Anchors Animations
    $("#lexuslink").click(function() {
        scrollToAnchor('lexus');
     });

     $("#fiatlink").click(function() {
        scrollToAnchor('fiat');
     });

     $("#merclink").click(function() {
        scrollToAnchor('merc');
     });

     $("#homelink").click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 900)
     });

     $("a").on('click', function(event) {

        // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
        if (this.hash !== "") {
          // Prevent default anchor click behavior
          event.preventDefault();

          // Store hash
          let hash = this.hash;

          // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
          // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
          $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
          }, 800, function(){
            window.location.hash = hash;
          });
        } 
      });

});

//E-mail Validation Function

$(".test").hide();

function validateForm() {
    const name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    if (name == "") {
        document.querySelector('.status').innerHTML = "Wypełnij wszystkie pola.";
        return false;
    }
    const email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    if (email == "") {
        document.querySelector('.status').innerHTML = "Wpisz swój adres email";
        return false;
    } else {
        const re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        if (!re.test(email)) {
            document.querySelector('.status').innerHTML = "Wpisz poprawny e-mail.";
            return false;
        }
    }
    const subject = document.getElementById('subject').value;
    if (subject == "") {
        document.querySelector('.status').innerHTML = "Wpisz temat wiadomości.";
        return false;
    }
    const message = document.getElementById('message').value;
    if (message == "") {
        document.querySelector('.status').innerHTML = "Message cannot be empty";
        return false;
    }
    document.querySelector('.status').innerHTML = "Wysyłanie...";
    document.getElementById('contact-form').submit();
}
```

There is my HTML File:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="keywords" content="samochody,do,ślubu,wynajem,lexus,fiat,zabytkowe,klasyczne,mercedes,fiat">
    <meta name="author" content="Daniel Mydlarz">
    <title>Samochody do ślubu - Oświęcim i okolice</title>
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="assets/css/now-ui-kit.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sass/baguetteBox.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sass/style.css">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="img/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="img/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="img/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Mansalva|Princess+Sofia&display=swap&subset=latin-ext"
        rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="code.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="landing-page sidebar-collapse">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-primary fixed-top navbar-transparent" color-on-scroll="300">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="dropdown button-dropdown d-lg-none">
                <a href="#pablo" class="dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <span class="button-bar"></span>
                    <span class="button-bar"></span>
                    <span class="button-bar"></span>
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-header">MENU</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#lexus">Samochody</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#galeria">Galeria</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#oferta">Oferta</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#kontakt">Kontakt</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="navbar-translate">

                <a class="align-baseline nav-link d-lg-none d-xl-none d-md-none float-left" rel="tooltip"
                    title="Zadzwon teraz aby dowiedziec sie wiecej" data-placement="bottom" href="tel:792-877-785"
                    target="_blank">
                    <i class="fa fa-phone" style="font-size:34px;color: white"></i>
                </a>

                <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#navigation" aria-controls="navigation-index" aria-expanded="false"
                    aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-bar top-bar"></span>
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-bar middle-bar"></span>
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-bar bottom-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse fx-start" id="navigation"
                data-nav-image="./assets/img/blurred-image-1.jpg">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">

                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" name="home" id="homelink" class="nav-link bleft">HOME</a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownbtn" href="" id="navbarDropdown" role="button"
                            data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Samochody
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuMenu">
                            <a href="#lexus" class="dropdown-item" id="lexuslink" name="itmlexus"
                                type="button">Lexus</a>
                            <a href="#fiat" class="dropdown-item" id="fiatlink" name="itmfiat" type="button">Fiat</a>
                            <a href="#merc" class="dropdown-item" id="merclink" name="itmmerc"
                                type="button">Mercedes</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>


                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#galeria" class="nav-link bleft">Galeria</a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#oferta" class="nav-link bleft">Oferta</a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#kontakt" class="nav-link bleft last">Kontakt</a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item position-right10">
                        <a class="nav-link" rel="tooltip" title="Zadzwon teraz aby dowiedziec sie wiecej"
                            data-placement="bottom" href="tel:792-877-785" target="_blank">
                            <i class="fa fa-phone" style="font-size:34px;color: white"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item position-right">
                        <a class="nav-link" rel="tooltip" title="Sprawdź nas na Facebook'u" data-placement="bottom"
                            href="https://www.facebook.com/Samochody-do-Ślubu-Oświęcim-i-okolice-586389625167858"
                            target="_blank">
                            <i class="fa fa-facebook-official" style="font-size:34px;color:white"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- End Navbar -->


    <div class="wrapper">





        <div class="container-fluid p-0" style="overflow:hidden">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="page-header page-header-small">
                    <div class="page-header-image" data-parallax="true"
                        style="background-image: url('img/slub-bg2.jpg')">
                    </div>
                    <div class="content-center welcome-text">
                        <div class="container-fluid landing-text">
                            <h1 class="h1-respononsive h1-title weird-font">Nowoczesne i klasyczne samochody do ślubu
                            </h1>
                            <h3 class="h3-responsive h3-title">Pozwól sobie na odrobinę luksusu...

                            </h3>
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down fa-4x arrow-down pb-2" id="scrollDown"
                                aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <main>
                    <section>
                        <a name="lexus"></a>
                        <div class="section pt-2 section-about-us">
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="row" id="lexus">
                                    <div class="col-md-8 ml-auto mr-auto text-center">
                                        <h2 class="h2-responsive 
                                    font-weight-bold title my-4 border-top border-bottom py-2">
                                            Nowoczesny Lexus</h2>
                                        <div class="container-lexus-photo pb-4">
                                            <img src="./img/bg-2.jpg" alt="Lexus" class="img-fluid">
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <a name="fiat" />
                                <div class="row" id="fiat">
                                    <div class="col-md-8 ml-auto mr-auto text-center">
                                        <h2 class="h2-responsive 
                                        font-weight-bold title my-4 border-top border-bottom py-2">
                                            Zabytkowy Fiat 126p</h2>
                                        <div class="container-lexus-photo pb-4">
                                            <img src="./img/fiat1.jpg" alt="Fiat 126p" class="img-fluid">
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <a name="merc" />
                                <div class="row" id="merc">
                                    <div class="col-md-8 ml-auto mr-auto text-center">
                                        <h2 class="h2-responsive 
                                            font-weight-bold title my-4 border-top border-bottom py-2">
                                            Klasyczny Mercedes</h2>
                                        <div class="container-lexus-photo pb-4">
                                            <img src="./img/merc1.jpg" alt="Mercedes" class="img-fluid">
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


            </div>
            </section>


            <!-- GALERIA  -->
            <h2 class="h2-responsive font-weight-bold text-center border-top border-bottom py-2" id="galeria">
                Galeria
            </h2>

            <section class="gallery-block grid-gallery">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="btn-group-ctn">

                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info filter" data-rel="all">Wszystkie</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info filter" data-rel="1">Lexus</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info filter" data-rel="3">Mercedes</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info filter" data-rel="2">Fiat 126p</button>
                    </div>


                    <div class="row gallery" id="gallery">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 item all pics animation 1">
                            <a class="lightbox" href="./img/1.jpg">
                                <img class="img-fluid image scale-on-hover" src="./img/1.jpg">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 item all pics animation 1">
                            <a class="lightbox" href="./img/2.jpg">
                                <img class="img-fluid image scale-on-hover" src="./img/2.jpg">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 item all pics animation 1">
                            <a class="lightbox" href="./img/3.jpg">
                                <img class="img-fluid image scale-on-hover" src="./img/3.jpg">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 item all pics animation 1">
                            <a class="lightbox" href="./img/4.jpg">
                                <img class="img-fluid image scale-on-hover" src="./img/4.jpg">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 item all pics animation 1">
                            <a class="lightbox" href="./img/5.jpg">
                                <img class="img-fluid image scale-on-hover" src="./img/5.jpg">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 item all pics animation 1">
                            <a class="lightbox" href="./img/6.jpg">
                                <img class="img-fluid image scale-on-hover" src="./img/6.jpg">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 item all pics animation 1">
                            <a class="lightbox" href="./img/7.jpg">
                                <img class="img-fluid image scale-on-hover" src="./img/7.jpg">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 item all pics animation 1">
                            <a class="lightbox" href="./img/8.jpg">
                                <img class="img-fluid image scale-on-hover" src="./img/8.jpg">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 item all pics animation 2">
                            <a class="lightbox" href="./img/fiat01.jpg">
                                <img class="img-fluid image scale-on-hover" src="./img/fiat01.jpg">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 item all pics animation 2">
                            <a class="lightbox" href="./img/fiat02.jpg">
                                <img class="img-fluid image scale-on-hover" src="./img/fiat02.jpg">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 item all pics animation 2">
                            <a class="lightbox" href="./img/fiat03.jpg">
                                <img class="img-fluid image scale-on-hover" src="./img/fiat03.jpg">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 item all pics animation 2">
                            <a class="lightbox" href="./img/fiat04.jpg">
                                <img class="img-fluid image scale-on-hover" src="./img/fiat04.jpg">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 item all pics animation 2">
                            <a class="lightbox" href="./img/fiat05.jpg">
                                <img class="img-fluid image scale-on-hover" src="./img/fiat05.jpg">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 item all pics animation 2">
                            <a class="lightbox" href="./img/fiat06.jpg">
                                <img class="img-fluid image scale-on-hover" src="./img/fiat06.jpg">
                            </a>
                        </div>


                        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 item all pics animation 3">
                            <a class="lightbox" href="./img/merc2.jpg">
                                <img class="img-fluid image scale-on-hover" src="./img/merc2.jpg">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 item all pics animation 3">
                            <a class="lightbox" href="./img/merc3.jpg">
                                <img class="img-fluid image scale-on-hover" src="./img/merc3.jpg">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 item all pics animation 3">
                            <a class="lightbox" href="./img/merc4.jpg">
                                <img class="img-fluid image scale-on-hover" src="./img/merc4.jpg">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 item all pics animation 3">
                            <a class="lightbox" href="./img/merc5.jpg">
                                <img class="img-fluid image scale-on-hover" src="./img/merc5.jpg">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 item all pics animation 3">
                            <a class="lightbox" href="./img/merc6.jpg">
                                <img class="img-fluid image scale-on-hover" src="./img/merc6.jpg">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 item all pics animation 3">
                            <a class="lightbox" href="./img/merc7.jpg">
                                <img class="img-fluid image scale-on-hover" src="./img/merc7.jpg">
                            </a>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>




            </main>
        </div>

        <h2 id="oferta" class="h2-responsive font-weight-bold text-center border-top border-bottom py-2 my-5">
            Oferta</h2>

        <section class="pricing py-5">
            <div class="container">

                <div class="row center-offer">
                    <!-- Free Tier -->
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        <div class="card mb-5 mb-lg-0">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h6 class="card-price text-center"><span class="period">od</span> 399 <span
                                        class="period">zł</span>
                                </h6>


                                <ul class="fa-ul">
                                    <h4 class="text-muted mt-1">Cena zawiera:</h4>
                                    <li>
                                        Wybrany samochód</li>
                                    <li>
                                        Dojazd do domu
                                        Pani młodej oraz Pana młodego</li>
                                    <li>
                                        Dojazd do kościoła
                                        pary młodej
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        Przejazd na
                                        weselną sale
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <a href="#kontakt" class="btn btn-block btn-primary text-uppercase">Zapytaj o
                                    wolne terminy</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>


        <section class="mb-4 pt-5 px-1" id="kontakt">
            <div class="container">

                <!--Section heading-->
                <h2 class="h2-responsive font-weight-bold text-center my-4 border-top border-bottom py-2">
                    Skontaktuj się z nami</h2>
                <!--Section description-->
                <p class="text-center w-responsive mx-auto mb-5">Masz jakieś pytania? Chcesz dobrać indywidualną
                    ofertę?
                </p>

                <div class="row">

                    <!--Grid column-->
                    <div class="col-md-9 mb-md-0 mb-5 contact-form">
                        <form id="contact-form" name="contact-form" action="mail.php" method="POST">

                            <!--Grid row-->
                            <div class="row">

                                <!--Grid column-->
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="md-form mb-0">
                                        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control">
                                        <label for="name" class="">Twoje imię</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!--Grid column-->

                                <!--Grid column-->
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="md-form mb-0">
                                        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="form-control">
                                        <label for="email" class="">Twój e-mail</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!--Grid column-->

                            </div>
                            <!--Grid row-->

                            <!--Grid row-->
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="md-form mb-0">
                                        <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" class="form-control">
                                        <label for="subject" class="">Temat</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!--Grid row-->

                            <!--Grid row-->
                            <div class="row">

                                <!--Grid column-->
                                <div class="col-md-12">

                                    <div class="md-form">
                                        <textarea type="text" id="message"
                                            placeholder="Witam, interesuję mnie wynajem samochodu w terminie ..."
                                            name="message" rows="2" class="form-control md-textarea"></textarea>
                                        <label for="message">Twoja wiadomość</label>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!--Grid row-->

                        </form>

                        <div class="text-center text-md-left">
                            <a class="btn btn-submit" onclick="validateForm()">Wyślij</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="status"></div>
                    </div>
                    <!--Grid column-->

                    <!--Grid column-->
                    <div class="col-md-3 text-center kontakt-info">
                        <ul class="list-unstyled mb-0">

                            <li>
                                <i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                <p>32-600 Oświęcim, <br>
                                    ul. Zagrodowa 31B</p>
                            </li>

                            <li><i class="fa fa-phone mt-4 fa-2x" style="color: black"></i>
                                <p>+48 792-877-785</p>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <i class="fa fa-envelope mt-4 fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" style="color: black"></i>
                                <p>kodiaqrentacar@gmail.com</p>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!--Grid column-->

                </div>
            </div>

        </section>
    </div>

    <!-- Plugins -->
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cookie-bar/cookiebar-latest.min.js?theme=white&always=1"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/baguettebox.js/1.11.0/baguetteBox.js" async></script>

    <!--   Core JS Files   -->

    <script src="assets/js/core/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/core/popper.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/core/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.7.6/js/mdb.min.js"></script>


    <!--  Plugin for Switches, full documentation here: http://www.jque.re/plugins/version3/bootstrap.switch/ -->
    <script src="assets/js/plugins/bootstrap-switch.js"></script>

    <!--  Plugin for the Sliders, full documentation here: http://refreshless.com/nouislider/ -->

    <script src="assets\js\plugins/nouislider.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!--  Plugin for the DatePicker, full documentation here: https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker -->
    <script src="assets/js/plugins/bootstrap-datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!--  Google Maps Plugin    -->
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY_HERE"></script>

    <!-- Control Center for Now Ui Kit: parallax effects, scripts for the example pages etc -->
    <script src="assets/js/now-ui-kit.js?v=1.3.0" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Maybe someone had similar problem, hope to see some tips from you guys. If you need another script just tell me hope we solve this together.

Best Regards Daniel.

Comment: can you please add you CSS here?

Comment: I had check your website and i found two issues regarding to you CSS file can you please add you CSS file here?

Comment: There is link to full respository: 
[link](https://github.com/szildaniel/autoslub) - _media.scss is RWD File, style.scss is main stylesheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to remove below css code form your css file.

```
.wrapper {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

and also need to update your font size for the element `#kontakt p` in media query of `576px` right now it is `1.1rem` you need to reduce it `0.9rem`.

I hope after done this two minor changes your scrolling problem will be solved.

Comment: just try to update your code as per my ans bro I am sure that your problem will be 100% solved. if this is not help full then tell me.

Comment: That's working great now. You made my day. Thanks bro!